# How to connect apache storm with grafana?

Tags: grafana, apache-storm, data-stream

I am collecting data in JSON format that I process in real time with apache storm. I would now like to use grafana to be able to perform real time visualizations on this processed data. Is there a way to connect storm to grafana?
I haven't found much information on the topic, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana is a visualization tool that can be set on top of a datastore such as Prometheus / ADX etc. You have first enable collection of these metrics into such a datastore.

Here is one such example https://github.com/wizenoze/storm-metrics-reporter-prometheus

Once this is done , any metrics that are reported from the code (Counter , Gauges , JMX metrics) are then saved on the data store that can then be visualized on Grafana